# Java Swing issue with JButton selecting/ActionPerformed

Tags: java, swing, jbutton

I'm currently developing a maze game and I have a setup where the user can change the controls, in order to do that there are several buttons corresponding to each game control (moving...etc). To change a game control the user must click the button, then press a key and after that the control key should have been updated such as the button text, it should appear like this: UP_MOVEMENT = NEW_CONTROL.
So if I want to change the UP_MOVEMENT key to the "P" key for example, I should click one time on the UP_MOVEMENT button, then press the "P" key and it should be done.
The problem is that once I click the button and after pressing the wanted key to see the button's text change I have to click on it again and I want it to be instantaneous. Here is a part of my code:

```
public JPanel createKeyBidings() {
    JPanel buttonBox = new JPanel();

    JButton upKey = new JButton("UP="+ KeyEvent.getKeyText(settings.getUp()));
    JButton downKey = new JButton("DOWN="+ KeyEvent.getKeyText(settings.getDown()));
    JButton leftKey = new JButton("LEFT="+KeyEvent.getKeyText(settings.getLeft()));
    JButton rigthKey=new JButton("RIGTH="+KeyEvent.getKeyText(settings.getRight()));
    JButton shoot = new JButton("SHOOT");

    upKey.addKeyListener(this);
    downKey.addKeyListener(this);
    leftKey.addKeyListener(this);
    rigthKey.addKeyListener(this);
    shoot.addKeyListener(this);

    upKey.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            if (keyPressed != null) {
                settings.setUp(keyPressed.getKeyCode());
                upKey.setText("UP=" + keyPressed.getKeyChar());
            }                   
        }
    });

    buttonBox.add(upKey);
    buttonBox.add(downKey);
    buttonBox.add(leftKey);
    buttonBox.add(rigthKey);
    buttonBox.add(shoot);

    return buttonBox;
}
```

Comment: Can you post the code in relation to the KeyListener? Where is keyPressed defined? Can you elaborate on the order of events (button pressed (press AND release)) and then key pressed)?

Comment: The cahin of events is : button pressed and released->key press. The keyPressed is a private variable defined in this Settings class where this JPanel is being created, the KeyListener 
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
  keyPressed = e;} ;
 It's all working fine, the control command changes and the button's text too, but as I said the problem is that i have to click 2 times on the button to see any change and I want it to do after the key is pressed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to react based upon a KeyPressed event, then you should consider placing the logic within the KeyListener methods. In other words, rather than keeping the last key pressed in the keyPressed variable, keep a buttonPressed variable that is set every time the ActionListener is fired. When a Key is pressed, check which button was last pressed and react accordingly. If you wish to only react when the button is held (pressed and before it is released rather than after it is released - when an ActionListener is fired), then in the KeyListener you can evaluate which button is pressed by checking the button is pressed through it's model (eg if ( myButton.getModel().isPressed() )

Comment: thank you man, I reordered the code and now it's all working fine, thanks ! I'd upvote if I had enough reputation >.>

Comment: No problem. You should still be able to mark your question as answered ;)

Comment: @copeg "then you should consider placing the logic within the" KeyBindings., a few virtuals keyboard here

Answer (score 0):

This may be a novice "work around" (as I'm new to Java/Swing) but try refreshing the `JFrame` right after you update the buttons text with:

`SwingUtilities.updateComponentTreeUI(yourJFrame);`

Or if that doesn't work try:

```
yourJFrame.invalidate();
yourJFrame.validate();
yourJFrame.repaint();
```

Comment: @coderdudo I'm sorry, I'm unsure as to what the problem is than. But I suggest following copeg's solution as it seems like a more "proper" way to go about solving the problem.

Comment: @coderdudo Also try adding my code into different points of your code. For example right before you add the buttons. I'm not sure if that'll make a difference but it's worth a shot. AND if this even works try replacing "yourJFrame" with "yourJPanel" or "yourJButton".

Comment: I opted to follow the lead given by copeg and it's working fine now, thank you